# Code to Test In Blazor WASM (make it NOT slow)

Tags: .net-core, process, devops, blazor

How can I faster test changes in Layout using Blazor?

I used to code websites in good old Apache+PHP+MySQL. and now I am starting with some development in Blazor.

But I find it difficult to work on the user interface. When I need to test a small change, for instance moving a entry in a web form from one row to another...

Blazor WASM development process:

- Edit the code
- Shutdown the browser
- Recompile (Pray that it compiles...)
- Wait for the webapp+API-App+Identity App to startup
- Navigate to the page I am making layout on.

PHP+X Process

- Edit the code
- Press F5

I wish for a similar experience.
How can I decrease the development code/test UI time when using Blazor?

Comment: Are you comparing the time it takes to run a script vs the time it takes to compile and run 3 applications? That's not a good starting point. Regardless, it seems to me you're doing something wrong, as you shouldn't have to stop debugging when you make a change in blazor

Comment: Yes, I am comparing them, I know that technically, it is a unfair comparison, but from a developer point of view, the experience is accurate. We are developing on a Blazor WASM app, maybe that is why it is not working when I change the .Razor files? The setup (as far as I know) is the standard Blazor WASM App from VS2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do interactive development is using `dotnet watch run` from a command prompt (I add a `.cmd` script to my projects to run this for the project). This will run the project and watch for changes to files, then re-compile the project.

On .NET 3.x Blazor you'll have to refresh the browser (F5). On .NET 5 projects it does this automatically.

You may also want to read [Rémi Bourgarel's Blog article](https://remibou.github.io/Make-your-Blazor-development-faster/) on this, although I am not sure all his points are still valid if you're using .NET 5.

Comment: Using dotnet watch run really improves the process! I tried the other tip mentioned in the article with disabling linking, but it didn't make any difference (compile time is about 4seconds from clean build) can Visual studio be setup in the same way so I can run with the debugger attached also?

Comment: Also, I think hot-reload is worth mentioning. You can see any changes that you have made instantly in the browser without the need to go through the compile process...

Comment: @Grizzlly yes, thanks- Hot Reload wasn't a thing when the original question/response was written, but it is now. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/hot-reload?view=aspnetcore-6.0